# Where can I download Discrete Mathematics lecture videos?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, self-learning, online-resources

Good morning,

I'm doing a course in Discrete Mathematics (so far: Four Colour Theorem, Intro Graph Theory, Intro Logic Theory, Intro Set Theory and Intro Proofs) at University, but unfortunately they don't record the lectures.

Where can I download Discrete Mathematics lecture videos? - If from multiple places, which would you recommend?

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

PS: Notes and worksheets recommendations would be great too :]

Comment: Alec, I removed the (logic) and (set-theory) tags, as they seem less relevant than (graph-theory) for example. They are intended for more advanced topics (advanced undergraduates and graduates studying logic/set theory).

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've been studying bioinformatics, and in an effort to get my biology up to scratch, I've been watching online lectures via [iTunes U](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/).  There's an astonishing number of free recorded lectures available, including discrete mathematics.

Typically the video and lecture quality is very high, although I have encountered a few lower quality videos.  I'd recommend trying them out before downloading a huge amount (some of the downloads can be quite large).

Comment: Had difficulty finding related Discrete Mathematics lectures on there...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look at  ADUni lectures

[ADUni Discrete Mathematics](http://www.aduni.org/courses/discrete/)

In addition there are Lecture Notes

Hopefully, it will be useful

Comment: Looked at them a while ago, might pursue and purchase there DVDs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of video lectures which someone can go through, some are already mentioned just making a list of most of them.

1. [Computer Sc - Discrete Mathematical Structures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0862D1A947252D20)
2. [Discrete Mathematics](http://www.aduni.org/courses/discrete/)

Since I have a reputation limitation not posting other links.

Answer (score 0):

You may find Steve Skeina's video lectures on Discrete Math very helpful
[Skeina's video lectures](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/math-video/)

Comment: Thanks, my lecturer actually linked me to those :]

Answer (score -1):

This is a late response, but MIT's OCW has materials for discrete mathematics.

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/